# Unit testing for a polymorphic has_many through relationship without active record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rspec

I've built an application where `users` can attend `events`.  They are mapped through a polymorphic relationship `attendable`, as I anticipate creating different things that can be attended in the future (parties, etc).

This is how it's modelled:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :attendances, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :events, :through => :attendances
end

class Attendance < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :attendable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :user
end

class Events < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many  :attendances, as: :attendable
  has_many  :users, :through => :attendances
end
```

I've created a rails service object `RegisterService`:

```
class RegisterService

  def initialize(event)
    @event = event
  end

  def register(users)
    reset_the_register
    users.each do |user|
      mark_user_as_present_on_run(user)
    end
    return @event.users
  end

  def mark_user_as_present_on_run(user)
    attendance = @event.attendances.build(:user_id => user.id)
    attendance.save
  end

  def reset_the_register
    @event.attendances.destroy_all
  end

end
```

And finally, I'm trying to create a unit test to test the register action, specifically checking that it returns a set of users:

```
require "spec_helper"

describe RegisterService do
  let(:event) { stub_model Event }
  let(:register_service) { RegisterService.new(event) }

  describe '#register' do

    let(:user_1) { stub_model User }
    let(:user_2) { stub_model User }
    let(:user_3) { stub_model User }
    let(:users) { [user_1, user_2] }

    it 'returns the fulfilled attendances' do
      attendees = register_service.register(users)
      expect(attendees).to include(user_1)
      expect(attendees).to include(user_2)
    end

  end
end
```

**The problem**

Having used `stub_model` to stub out the instances `event`, `user_1`, `user_2`, etc, attendees is reported back as `#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy []>` - and is empty.

If I use FactoryGirl instead to create records for event, user, etc, all works fine - but obviously this has the undesired result that it's having to hit the database (since it uses ActiveRecord).

Any ideas why specing is having this result, and suggests for working around this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Mike Feathers is not staring over your shoulder, right? Hit the database!

Seriously - if the DB participates in the unit of logic you are testing, you need the DB. Writing tests that generally don't hit the DB is just a mind-game that helps us decouple things. And it helps speed up tests that might accidentally run the DB slowly. But we follow these rules so we can break them when we need to.

Comment: I'm just trying to keep the test suite running as fast as possible, and ActiveRecord is notoriously slow.

Comment: Noted, but that's a bug in how the test runner sets up the database. Sry I've never found a fix...